# Swap sublist of different length in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I’m trying to swap the position of items in a list.

Like this:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  # Original list
i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6] # Indexes
A[i:k], A[j:w] = A[j:w], A[i:k]
# Expected A: [4,5,6,3,1,2]
print(A)
A: [4,5,6,1,2,6] # Six is repeated and I’ve lost the item 3.
```

I have tried things like:
A[i:k+1], A[j:w-1] = A[j:w] , A[i:k]
and so on, but none of them worked.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Is your expected output actually `[4,5,6,3,1,2]` or did you mean `[4,5,6,1,2,3]`?

Comment: Actually [4,5,6,3,1,2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, A[0:2] includes only elements at index 0 and 1, 2 means till index 2 but not element at index 2.
So when you assign A[0:2] A[3:6] you are actually replacing 2 elements of list with three elements.
Another approach can be
`A = A[j:w]+ A[k:j]+ A[i:k]`
Your approach was neglecting the element at index 2 which was 3.

Comment: Ive made it more general with: A = A[0:i] + A[j:w]+ A[k:j]+ A[i:k] + A[w:] and seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

***Slicing in Python:***

Hi there, In Python indexing there is an important concept you have to know, When you slice a list the left index is not included, the following code will show that:

```
#A list with numbers from 0 to 5
alist = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

#look here the index five is not included
print(alist[0:5]) #output= [0,1,2,3,4]

#index 5 is included because Python takes the last index before Index 6
print(alist[0:6]) #output= [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

for more info:

[1. Slicing in python w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp)

[2. A video about slicing in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajrtAuDg3yw&pp=ygURc2xpY2luZyBpbiBweXRob24%3D)

***by Returning to your code:***

```
i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6] #indexes 
# 0:2     3:6      3:6    0:2
A[i:k], A[j:w] = A[j:w], A[i:k]
```

Look at the index **0:2**, it equals the elements 1,2 only, but, you didn't want that, you want the elements 1,2,3 and from what I said in the first, a[0:3] = [1,2,3], So you have to change the variable "k" to 3 instead of 2.

***Why the last element in output is 6:***

To know that, track the code:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  #original list
i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6] #indexes 
A[i:k], A[j:w] = A[j:w], A[i:k]
           
output A: [4,5,6, # the index from 3:6
          1,2 #the index from 0 to 2]
          6 #you didn't change it so it doesn't change
```

Here is the full code:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  #original list
i,k,j,w = [0,3,3,6] #indexes 
# 0:3     3:6      3:6     0:3
A[i:k], A[j:w] = A[j:w], A[i:k]

print(A)
```

Comment: This answer helps you to get the following result: A = [4,5,6,1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of different intepretations for your question

The first two rely on your indexes as

```
A[i:k] = [1,2]
```

rather than `[1,2,3]`

This is as `[i:k]` goes up to but does not include the element at `k`
This can be fixed by changing `i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6]` to `i,m,w = [0,3,6]` where the second soloutioun uses m as a midpoint.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  
i,m,w = [0,3,3,6]
A = A[m:w]+A[i:m][::-1]
```

`[::-1]` is a way to reverse a list and does the same as reversed()

so the last line could also be changed to this
`A = A[m:w]+list(reversed(A[i:m]))`

Or assuming you did mean  `i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6]` we can fix this using  `[i:k+1]`

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  
i,k,j,w = [0,2,3,6]
A = A[j:w]+A[i:k+1][::-1]
```

Or if you just wanted the midpoint and reverse one half of the list as seen in msSpruijt's answer

```
m = len(A)//2
A = A[:m]+A[m][::-1]
```